# How to validate MATLAB local cluster profile from the command line?

Tags: matlab

To validate a local profile in MATLAB, below steps are suggested:

1. Go to the Parallel menu in MATLAB and select "Manage Cluster Profiles..." ("Manage Configurations..." for R2011b or earlier)
2. Highlight your local scheduler configuration and click the "Validate" button ("Start Validation" for R201b or earlier)

But apparently, those steps are only possible if you are able to have a display option. I am running MATLAB in a linux server with no display, and I am wondering how to do above steps from the command line, and get a detailed result.

Comment: Not sure you can. I once looked for this option and couldn't find it. What about connecting to the server with X11 forwarding, so you can use the GUI? You only need do it once.